# Node Express session not persisting

Tags: node.js, html, cordova, session, express

i have an odd problem with Express session object: when i use my application (a simple HTML5/JQM website single page app) as a web application (that is, my pages are on my node server), session object of Express works correctly; but if i try to use my app as an HTML page (obviously pointing its services to the node.js server application), in the same way a Cordova app would (and in fact i would like to use it like that) my sessionid changes at every get/post request i do; this has the effect that my session is always re-created, and the variables i stored into the session do not persist through my app...  I have the need to make a Cordova app from my current website; what am i missing ?

Have done a lot of research about the matter, and also found some solutions, that do not work in my case....

I set a session variable at login (a simple json object), then update it through the course of the app (adding basically items to an array contained into the json var in session); it works only whenever i update the var into one specific route; but then i need to access the session object from another route, and i always find it empty; this, as i previously said, does not happen when i use the app as a web app (http://localhost:3000/index.html); but it happens when i open the html file directly (as a Cordova app would do); hope i was sufficiently clear

Thanks in advance

Here are some of my code excerpts

**code excerpts:**

**app.js   (main node.js server app)**

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended : false
}));
app.use(favicon(__dirname + '/public/img/bluemix_logo.png'));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(session({ 
 'cookie': {
            'httpOnly': false,
            'maxAge': 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 60,
        },
secret: 'keyboard cat' }));    //used same parameters i found on 
//..............
app.use('/', index);
app.use("/installations",installations)
```

**installations.js (route for /installations path)**

```
var installBuffer=[];

router.post('/addItem', function(req, res) {
    var tipo = req.body.tipo;   
    var aas = req.body.assignee; 
    var location = req.body.location;
    sess=req.session;
    var l=installBuffer.length;
    var idx=l++;
    installBuffer[idx]=req.body;    //here i add an item to installBuffer
    sess.installBuffer = installBuffer;  //and here i put it into session
    console.log("session: "+JSON.stringify(sess));  //this works ok
    //at any reference to this route items are incremented correctly
    res.send("additem");
});


router.post('/addItem/addInstallation', function(req, res) {
    sess=req.session;
   console.log("session: "+req.session); //here session is always empty
    // with its default json vars cookie, httponly, etc...
    res.send("addinstallation");
});
```

As i stated before, this behaviour is only when i use the html5 single page as a local page (as it would be in a cordova/phonegap app).
This does not happen at all when using the page as a web app (http://localhost/index.html), in this mode it works perfectly

Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you share some of the app configuration, the routing and controllers. I'm sure it would help others pinpoint the exact issue.

Comment: It would be good if you could show how your configuring the session middleware and interacting with it in the controllers.

Comment: don't think i have controllers; i have a main app.js directing to the routes depending on the url, and the problem i have is in the installations.js route; nothing more, using express and the req.session object.

As i said, my code works correctly when using the single page HTML as a web page on a web site.. But, i need to make it a Cordova, and in the plain HTML5 file (accessing remotely the services of the node app.js server) it shows this problem

Comment: How your registering the session middleware, configuring the session store and registering your router.  Basically, the excerpts from the global app object would suffice now, but best add these to your question so that users don't have to dig extensively through the comments.

Comment: @DemyMortelliti Don't add your code in the comments section. Please edit your question with your updated code examples in a format that is readable to help people answer.